Echidna: No bytecode found for contract
I am currently trying to use echidna for a project that uses foundry but while running the echidna .
➜  eurodollar-protocol git:(master) ✗ echidna . 
[2024-11-11 10:05:28.53] Compiling .... Done! (2.922725s)
Multiple contracts found, only analyzing the first
Analyzing contract: /Users/codertjay/GolandProjects/eurodollar-protocol/lib/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/contracts/access/AccessControlUpgradeable.sol:AccessControlUpgradeable
echidna: No bytecode found for contract "/Users/codertjay/GolandProjects/eurodollar-protocol/lib/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/contracts/access/AccessControlUpgradeable.sol:AccessControlUpgradeable"

i get this error

i fixed it by targeting the contract. I was using
echdina .
but this works
echidna   src/echidna/EchidnaYieldOracle.sol --contract  YieldOracleEchidnaTest   --test-mode assertion 

